# Search for Text within Multiple PowerPoint files

Tags: python, powerpoint

I am trying to write a code that looks through a list of PowerPoints and flags those that contain a specific string (in this case, the last name "Jones"). Any idea why this would be happening?

This displays results if I replace 'Jones' with 'text'

```
from pptx import Presentation
import glob

direct = r"C:\Users\xxxx\Downloads\*.pptx"

for eachfile in glob.glob(direct):
    prs = Presentation(eachfile)
    print(eachfile)
    print("----------------------")
    for slide in prs.slides:
        for shape in slide.shapes:
            if hasattr(shape, "Jones"):
                print(shape.text)
            else:
                print("None")
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear. What exactly is happening when you run this code, and what exactly do you *want* to happen?

Comment: When I run the code I just get "None" over and over for 40 slides. What I am looking for is 39 iterations (slides) of "None" and 1 showing "Jones" (this is the last slide in the deck that has contact information)

Comment: So, are you sure that the `shape` has an attribute called `"Jones"`?